# Does every infinite field contain the integers as a subring?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

I simply ask because if $1+1=2(1)=2$ then this would imply that all positive integers are contained, and as every element in a field has a negative all the negative integers are contained. At the same time every "reciprocal" would be contained as every element has an inverse. Which leads me to believe at least some section of the rational numbers (excluding integers) is also contained in every infinite field.

How close am I to correct, as surely this would also imply that the integers are a subring of every infinite ring as well?

EDIT: Okay I think the qualifier here is if it has characteristic $0$.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_2(X)$... Do you know this field?? Is it infinite??? Does it contain all integers??

Comment: Yeah, I think, is that related to integers modulo 2? In any case that has answered my question about rings because polynomial rings don't contains all integers

Comment: So...Any further questions?

Comment: DO all fields of characteristic zero have this property, at least?

Comment: Yesss!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If you want to listen further, every field of characteristic $0$ contains not only integers but also all rational numbers.....

Comment: There, I thought I was at least onto something, I was just trying to figure out exactly which fields do, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!!

Comment: I was thinking that it would contain the rationals as well, but that seemed like a bit of step too far since I knew there was something missing about my reasoning for the integers

Comment: So, Any further questions??

Comment: This one is perhaps a bit less mathematical, but would that means that all infinite fields of characteristic 0 (that aren't just the rationals) are simply different extensions of the rational numbers, so we go one way we get the real numbers, we go the other and we get a new system altogether

Comment: Yes.... $~~~~~$

Comment: Okay I'll stop with the obvious questions :P I've got it all

Comment: Very Good!! :D :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning (maybe formalised a little bit further) shows that every (infinite) field *of characteristic $0$* contains (a isomorphic copy of) the ring of integers, hence also (a isomorphic copy of) the field of rational numbers (which is the field of fractions of the ring of integers). As pointed out in the comments, a field of characteristic $p$ contains a isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, so does that means that you can classify all those fields as extensions of a field of integers modulo P?

Comment: Well, I would not use the word "classify" actually. For a field, being of characteristic $p\geq 0$ means precisely to contain an isomorphic copy of $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$. So what you get is not an actual classification, but rather a characterisation (or a definition, if you prefer) of fields of characteristic $p$.

Comment: @Nethesis Note, there is no finite field of characteristic zero.

Comment: Could you not classify {0} as a field?

Comment: Okay, thank you, that all makes complete sense

Comment: I am not completely sure I can get your point, but the fact is that the characteristic of a field is either zero or a prime number. Nevertheless, it is always meaningful to write that a field of characteristic $p\geq 0$ contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, even when $p=0$, as $\mathbb{Z}/0\mathbb{Z}\simeq \mathbb{Z}$...

Answer (score 1):

No. Any copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ must be the ring generated by $1$, but in any infinite field of prime characteristic $p$, $$\underbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}_p = 0,$$ and so the ring generated by $1$ is not isomorphic to the integers.

**Edit** Under the condition that the field have characteristic $0$, this *is* true, essentially because in such a field the above equation does not hold for any (nonzero) $p$.